# How to join two table so that result contains values from second table in between values of first table

Tags: c#, mysql, oracle, join

`TABLE 1 (ID,PID,PNO)` contains start and end point for eg; (A, B). with Primary Key (ID, PID) Foreign Key (ID)

`TABLE 2 (ID,PNO)` contains middle point information in order (a1,a2 ... bn-1, bn). with Primary Key (ID)

I am trying to join them in such a way that i can get [A, a1, a2 ... bn-1 , bn, B].

I fetched data using

```
SELECT PNO FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID= 123 UNION SELECT PNO FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID= 123
```

and tried it in C# code by fetching all data and then adding condition's and reordering them. This attempt is two lengthy.

Apart from this is there a way to join these two tables to get the result set.

Note : These tables are related to each other by common field ID, and The PID in TABLE1 one has two distinct value's like 1 for start and 2 for end. based on this the PNO with 1 should come first and PNO with 2 is expected to come at end.

Answer (score 0):

> "tried it in C# code by fetching all data and then adding condition's and reordering them".

This is usually a very bad idea, especially if you have a lot of network activity.  SQL is very good at manipulating data: in fact it is optimized for that task. So, try passing the conditions to the database as a WHERE clause, using an ORDER BY to sort the final result set and returning just the rows you need.  This could have a big impact on the total elapsed time if there is a large difference between the number of rows in the raw database set and the final C# set.

Other things.  If you're still finding this too slow you have a standard tuning problem.  You haven't provided any of the hard information necessary to give a definitive solution, so here are some guesses.

You want all the records for an ID so there isn't a more efficient way of joining the two intermediary result sets to get a final set.  But if the two sets are exclusive - that is, if the endpoints in `Table1` are not included in the points from `Table2` (your question isn't completely clear on this) - a UNION ALL would be more efficient:

```
SELECT PNO FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID= 123 
UNION ALL
SELECT PNO FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID= 123
```

That's because UNION makes an additional operation to produce a distinct set of values. Skipping that step will save you some time.

An index on `table2 ( ID, PNO)` could speed up retrieval times by avoiding the need to touch the table at all.  Whether it's worth the overhead of maintaining an index depends on how often you want to run this query and how you load `Table2`.  It also depends on what further filters you apply if you act on my opening paragraph.

Comment: The    PID    in TABLE1 one has two distinct value's like 1 for start and 2 for end. based on this the PNO with 1 should come first and PNO with 2 is expected to come at end.

Comment: That still isn't clear.  Please edit your question with some actual sample data  instead of the pseudo-values.